# Facing problem when return an array from a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, web, frontend, return-value

I am creating a function to fetch the latitude and longitude using navigator object and returning these two values using an array. The problem is that when I am trying to access one of them using indexing eg:array[0] it's printing undefined and when I am accessing it in console directly everything works fine. Even if I print the whole array in code not in the console directly it also works fine. I am adding a photo for the reference in case I am unable to explain the problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated[photo for more clear understanding statement no.13 printing undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vxRg.jpg)

Comment: Add your code so that we can reproduce your problem. Screenshots/images don't count

Answer (score 0):

```
async function getLocation() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            var array=new Array();
            if(navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
                    array.push(position.coords.latitude);
                    array.push(position.coords.longitude);
                    resolve(array);
                });
            }
            else {
                resolve(false);
            }
        });
    }
```

Then just await it, like this:

```
let user_location=await getLocation();
```

Or not:

```
getLocation().then(result =>
        console.log(result)
        );
```

Comment: Remove asyn and await simply handle the promise using then and it works fine Thanks for your help